# Unable to search output of Cisco show command using Ansible

Tags: ansible, cisco

Running Ansible 2.7.4

I have the following code:

```
- hosts: switches
  tasks:
  - name: show run on remote devices
    ios_command:
      commands: show run
    register: output

  - name: Display The Results
    debug:
      msg: "Enable Secret Found"
    when: ('secret' in output.stdout)
```

I want to read in the output of a show run command on a Cisco switch and then search that output for specific phrases in the output.
If a match is found I want a message to be displayed to the screen, however no match is ever found.

PLAY [switches] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.10.2.68]

TASK [show run on remote devices] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.10.2.68]

TASK [Display The Results] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.10.2.68]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.10.2.68                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

I have also tried altering the when statement to

```
when: output.stdout.find('enable') != -1
```

but this gives me the following error:

fatal: [10.10.2.68]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output.stdout.find('enable') != -1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.stdout.find('enable') != -1): 'list object' has no attribute 'find'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/showrun2.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Display The Results\n    ^ here\n"}

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> 'list object' has no attribute 'find'

I'm not sure how much clearer you would expect the error message to be, but in that circumstance `output.stdout` is a `list`, not a `str`

So you'll want

```
"enable" in (output.stdout | join("\n"))
```

or the strictly pythonic way

```
"enable" in "\n".join(output.stdout)
```